# How to resolve the Botkit.slackbot is not a function error for my code while trying to build a slackbot using botkit?

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api, botkit

I am trying to make a slackbot using botkit and I have written a code however I get the following error when I try to run it-

```
TypeError: Botkit.slackbot is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Postman Projects\botkitBot\mybot\index.js:27:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

This is the part in the code where I get the error:

```
const controller = Botkit.slackbot({
     debug: false,
     //include "log: false" to disable logging
});
```

I tried installing yeoman and slack adapter but its still not working.
It seems like its not a very common problem as its not acknowledged anywhere.
Please do help. It is the very basic step and I can't proceed if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

check the version of package installed by using this command

```
npm list botkit
```

it seems like new version has changed the specification if it shows 4.0 , try to uninstall it

```
npm uninstall botkit
```

and install the specific version which has this function in specification

```
npm install botkit@0.6
```

Comment: Okay Thanks! I'll try doing this!

Comment: So version was not the issue. The code that I had didn't work so I eventually cloned a Git repository provided in one of the YouTube videos and altered that code. Also I used "Dialogflow Middleware" for the integration, incase anyone comes across this same issue, you can try using "Dialogflow Middleware".

Comment: It would be better to use Botkit v4 as documented in https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/tree/master/packages/botbuilder-adapter-slack

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one. I had the same issue and it is indeed relating to the version.

Comment: here is the version suited : `npm install --save botkit@0.7.4`